# Import a created redux store to dispatch an action from a non connected component

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am using react-native and redux. I am also using react navigation, I have a bottom tab navigator where the second RouteConfig navigationOptions provides a function for tabBarOnPress. I want to dispatch some action to redux inside this callback.

```
import store from "./Store"    

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        First: FirstScreen,
        Second: {
           screen: SecondScreen,
           navigationOptions: {
               tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation }: any) => {
                   store.dispatch(someAction())
                   navigation.navigate("SecondScreenModal");
               }
           }
        },
        Third: ThirdScreen
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        //..
    }
);
```

As I can't find a way to connect the bottom tab navigator, I would like to know if it is bad practice in this case to directly import the created redux store (the same one I pass as a prop to the provider).

```
import rootReducer from "./RootReducer";
import {createStore} from "redux";

store = createStore(rootReducer)     
export default store
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the screen that you wish to dispatch the redux action (in your case SecondScreen), set a navigation param equal to the function you want to execute. You can name the parameter anything, but I usually name it according to how I will use it.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.props.navigation.setParams({ tabBarOnPress: this.props.myReduxActionCreator })
}
```

Then inside your screens navigation options, you can do something like this to access the function. Make sure its the same parameter name from above, so in this exmaple, 'tabBarOnPress'

```
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    First: FirstScreen,
    Second: {
      screen: SecondScreen,
      navigationOptions: {

        // Access the function inside navigation params here
        tabBarOnPress: ({navigation}) => navigation.getParam('tabBarOnPress', null)
      }
    },
    Third: ThirdScreen
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({})
  }
)
```

Comment: Very good answer to solve my problem regarding react-navigation. However that don't really answer if it is a bad practice to use directly an exported store instead of the classic provider/connect way. Could you also precise that point?

Comment: actually my params are undefined, FirstScreen and ThirdScreen being StackNavigator could that be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

After `const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator()` this complete code crate `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` arrow functions.

```
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BottomTab);
```

i believe you want to do like this.

Comment: createBottomTabNavigator() is a function that returns a component, and takes two paremeters RouteConfig and NavigationOptions. How do you expect to access this.props.dispatch inside navigationOptions: {
               tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation }: any) => {
                   store.dispatch(someAction())
                   navigation.navigate("SecondScreenModal");
               }
           } ?